# Пословица "Грамота - второй язык"

Tags: значения

Мы прочитали эту пословицу вчера.  Дочка хотела узнать значение.  Я сказал, что первый язык то, с которым вкусить.  Есть ли второе значение, нечто более глубоко?

Comment: Честно говоря, не встречал такой пословицы. Есть другая: "Грамота - второй язык".

Comment: Гмм.  Вы - правы.  Я путал, потому что сейчас я на работе и ее домашняя задание дома.  Итак, пожалуйста, объясни "грамота - второй язык".  Она тоже занималась вчера "Речь красна слушанием".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть две вещи: (1) устная речь; и (2) письменная словесность.
Грамота, это умение создать вторую вещь, письменную словесность.

Грамотей есть тот, кто грамотно *пишет.* Учиться грамоте значит изучать, как можно устную речь (1) записать в письменном виде (2). Способ письма определён через различные начертания букв, например, через прописные, заглавные, строчные, печатные и т.д. Буква в ее конкретном начертании называется по-русски литера (from Latin *littera* (also *`litera`*) "graphic symbol, alphabetic sign of the alphabet"). Отсюда, очень легко запомнить перевод:

```
  Грамота = literacy
```

*Устная речь* есть понятие более общее, чем понятие *язык.*  Можно знать свой родной язык (the mother tongue), **это первый язык,** и еще иностранные языки (foreign languages), и говорить на разных языках в нашей устной речи. Тот первый из иностранных языков, который по счёту станет **вторым языком,** изучать всегда трудно.

Если мы теперь приравняем по трудности, по полезности, по затратам времени изучение нашего первого иностранного языка **(второго языка)** к изучению письменной словесности на своём родном языке, то есть, **приравняем к грамоте,** то мы и получим предложение:

```
  “Грамота — второй язык”
```

Можно заметить, что латинский язык остался только в виде одной своей половины, письменного языка, письменной словесности.

В пословице смысл слова *грамота* переносится на словосочетание *"словесная письменность"*, а  смысл *"равный в изучении с иностранным языком"* — на словосочетание *"второй язык,"* и они успешно приравниваются в записи пословицы.

Мы говорим: оба слова, *грамота* и *язык,* использованы в переносном смысле.

---

<sub>Первые значения для слов пословицы, взятые из словаря, не годятся для выяснения смысла пословицы, как говорят в математике, здесь термины с разными объемами понятия (с разными смыслами), поэтому просто так их приравнять нельзя. Это не тождество, выраженное через тире "—", а уравнение, в котором нужно найти решение.</sub>

Comment: The explanation is absolutely right yet it's verbose and could be hard to understand for the foreigner. In short, that means "Learning to write in a native language is as hard as learning a foreign language".

Comment: Спасибо за хорошо выработанный ответ!

Answer (score 5):

Что то вы запутали. Грамота - это письменность. Язык - средство общения. Смысл пословицы - письменность второе средство общения. А краткость сестра таланта.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что эта пословица о том, что иногда бывает сложно понять неграмотного человека. С одной стороны мы говорим на одном и том же языке, но его неграмотность равносильна тому, как если бы мы говорили на разных языках. В этом смысле овладевание грамотностью сравнимо с изучением нового "второго" языка.

Comment: Прекрасно объяснили, спасибо.